# Auto fill in multiple date fields in multi page pdf, Acrobat DC PRO

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, pdf-form

i'm trying to make a PDF that contains multiple pages with forms that were paper forms. i have imported them into pdf, added text fields and am trying to find ways to fill out these forms quicker.
There is a text field for the DATE on multiple pages. on 1 page i need the dat in this format 200129 =YYMMDD format, and in the other pages i need it as 29-JAN-2020. is there a way i can select date or enter the date in 1 place, maybe in a special text box and link the other ones to get their data from the master text box with the date?

Answer (score 1):

In general, just using the same field name across all pages will cause one to update the value of the others but because you want a different format for the same date value on all pages after number 1, you need to use a calculation. If you make the date on page one the "master", the date field on all subsequent pages can be calculated from that to be the same value. The date fields on all subsequent pages can use the same field name.

If your date field on page one is named "date_1", then add the following code to the other date fields in the field calculation tab...

```
 event.value = this.getField("date_1").value;
```

You'll then need to use the Acrobat UI to set the format to what you want.

That's it.

Comment: Although if the form gets big, it may be better to "push" the value from the entry/master field to the subsequent fields.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i added a Date and renamed the other fields the same way and it automatically adds it into those fields.almost all places need the same format as the master format, DD-MM-YY, but only in 1 place in the form it must be like YYMMDD but the problem that i want this to be in a text box that will already have a few defautl characters like this: date/<here is where i want the YYMMDD to go> ? can it be done? so the textbox will look like this: date/200130 , (with date/ being the default value and 200130 being the imported date from the master box